Адъективация причастий
В словосочетании давящая повязка причастие "давящая" перешло в прилагательное?
Для примера можно взять такое предложение: "Мне наложили давящую повязку на рану".
Мне кажется, что да, ведь есть синонимы ("тугая", "сильно закрепленная") и нет зависимого слова.

• Мне наложили да́вящую повязку на рану.
Думаю, что в этом предложении да́вящую действительно является прилагательным:
повязку (какую?) давящую; наложили (на что? куда?) на рану.
В БТС Кузнецова:
1. только да́вящий. Тугой, сильно сдавливающий. Да́вящая повязка.
По толковому словарю Ефремовой слово давящий является только прилагательным (во всех значениях):
I давя́щий, прил.
1. Щемящий (о боли).
2. Тягостный, гнетущий.
II давя́щий, да́вящий, прил.
Сильно сдавливающий; удушающий.
давящий (словари на "Грамоте")

Специальный термин в МЕДИЦИНЕ, только в этом значении это прилагательное.
Поэтому наличие синонимов или зависимых слов не влияет на решение.
Давящая повязка применяется для временной остановки кровотечения из мягких тканей в 80% случаев. Особенно эффективна давящая повязка при поверхностных ранениях головы и конечностей, для остановки наружных венозных и капиллярных кровотечений.
В словаре РАН стоит обратить внимание на  значения, в котором давящий считается прилагательным.
Словари
ДАВЯЩИЙ
Русский орфографический словарь
давящий, прич.

ДАВЯЩИЙ
Русский орфографический словарь
давящий, прил. (тягостный, гнетущий)

ДАВЯЩИЙ
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ДАВЯЩИЙ; ДАВЯЩИЙ, -ая, -ее. 1. только дАвящий. 
Тугой, сильно сдавливающий. Д-ая повязка. 2. Тупой, 
ноющий, щемящий (о боли). 3. Тягостный, гнетущий. 
Д- ая тоска. Д-ее впечатление.

